# PHP APC and Memcache Benchmarking

Tags: php, memcached, apc

Is there any simple test I can try to benchmark APC and Memcache, just to get a sense of the performance benefits of using them?

I tried some simple stuff using microtime() and looping requests to my database and storing the results, first in cache and then without, but I didn't notice any significant performance boost.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The real benefit is not easy to test.  The problem is the are they help with is concurrency, not just page execution time...  And that's a non-trivial thing to test.

One option, would be to use `ab` (Apache Bench) to issue repeated HTTP requests to the same page, and measure the difference in request rate and load...

```
ab -c 20 -n 1000 http://www.example.com/index.php
```

The `-c 20` says to use 20 concurrent clients (simulating 20 simultaneous users).  The `-n 1000` says to make a total of 1000 requests.  Then, look at both the Time Per Request and the Requests Per Second fields.  Play around with different APC/Memcache settings (even disabling them) to watch how those figures change...

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I disable APC and Memcache, and run the command, I get the following: apr_socket_recv: An existing connection was forcibly closed. But when APC and Memcache are active, I don't get the error. Do you know what might be causing this? I'm using Windows and XAMPP (PHP 5.3.1)

Comment: Check your PHP and Apache error logs.  The chances are that something either segfaulted, or php died because of some other reasons...